# Changes in PHP.INI for OpenLiteSpeed not working

Tags: php, litespeed

In a OpenLiteSpeed server I used `php_info()` to find the path to `php.ini`

`Loaded Configuration File    /usr/local/lsws/lsphp73/etc/php/7.3/litespeed/php.ini`

Then I edited `max_input_vars` and tried several ways to restart OpenLiteSpeed to apply the changes, but nothing is working.

`php_info()` shows the old value of `max_input_vars`

Comment: did you `pkill lsphp` ?

Comment: @qtwrk this fixed my problem.
thank you very much friend!!!

Answer (score 9):

As told by @qtwrk `pkill lsphp` fixed the problem